# Textfield toggling Bool when clicked

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Bool value titled editMode which determines if the user can edit information on a current page. When this is toggled true and I enter a textfield, the Bool is flipped back to false. This only occurs on the first click into the textfield. On subsequent clicks into the textfield, it does not toggle (working fine)

How can I fix this issue?

```
struct RecipeControllerModal: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss // << dismiss view
    
    @ObservedObject var rm = RecipeLogic()
    @ObservedObject var ema = EditModeActive() // calling in next view
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                VStack{
                RecipeDashHeader(ema: ema) // <<passing  editMode
                    .padding() 
                      }
                   }
              }
```

**RecipeDashHeader // <<textfield view**

```
struct RecipeDashHeader: View {
    @State var recipeName = ""
    @ObservedObject var ema: EditModeActive
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if ema.editMode {
            VStack{
                    TextField(recipeName, text: $recipeName)
                        .foregroundColor(!ema.editMode ? Color.black : Color.red)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding()
                        
                    
                    .onChange(of: recipeName, perform: { _ in
                        ema.recipeTitle = recipeName
                    })
                }
```

**Published EditMode Variable**

```
class EditModeActive: ObservableObject {
    @Published var editMode: Bool = false
    @Published var recipeTitle = ""
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some code missing but shouldn't `ema` in the first view be declared using `@StateObject` instead?

Comment: Tried to leave out the unimportant snippets. I did make the switch before this post to StateObject and it yields the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Your `EditModeActive` which `ema` is, does not have a `recipeTitle` that you use in your `.onChange(...)`. The code you show should not even compile. Show a real working example code that produces your problem.

Comment: Apologies, just edited recipeTitle. I must have snipped it out when deleting the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using the `ema.recipeTitle` directly in your `TextField` and
using `@StateObject var ema` as mentioned in the comments.

Here is the example code I used in my tests:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RecipeControllerModal()
    }
}

struct RecipeControllerModal: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss // << dismiss view
    
//    @ObservedObject var rm = RecipeLogic()  // for testing
    @StateObject var ema = EditModeActive() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{  // <-- here should use NavigationStack
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    RecipeDashHeader(ema: ema) // <<passing  editMode
                        .padding()
                }
                // for testing
                Button(ema.editMode ? "save" : "edit") {
                    ema.editMode.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RecipeDashHeader: View {
    // @State var recipeName = "" // <-- here not needed
    @ObservedObject var ema: EditModeActive
    
    var body: some View {
        if ema.editMode {
            VStack{
                TextField(ema.recipeTitle, text: $ema.recipeTitle)  // <-- here
                    .foregroundColor(!ema.editMode ? Color.black : Color.red) // <--- usesless here ema.editMode == true always
                    .font(.title2)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                    .border(.red)
                // not needed
//                    .onChange(of: ema.recipeTitle, perform: { name in
//                        ema.recipeTitle = name
//                    })
            }
        } else {
            Text(ema.recipeTitle)
        }
    }
}

class EditModeActive: ObservableObject {
    @Published var editMode: Bool = false
    @Published var recipeTitle: String = "recipe title"  // <-- here
}
```